# How to fill with a vertical gradient for bar charts with the Shinobi iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, charts, shinobi

Shinobi currently supports a horizontal gradient for the bar chart (SChartColumnSeries).  Is there a way to fill with a vertical gradient? As shown here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to achieve this effect using a ShinobiCharts column or bar chart. It is however on the roadmap to add this kind of functionality, so do check back for a future release.